# Loading animation from server?

Tags: libgdx

As android app that will be playing animation online, it will be connected via web-socket to a server.

The question is, what is the recommend way to store animation that will be loaded by the android app?
I can send JSON formatted messaged via websocket, but as I am new to 3D animation, what format is advised for my case using LibGDX?

Comment: Why do you want to store animations on the server anyways? The client should handle all graphics and the server should just tell the client what graphic to load e.g. `server.sendToAll(new DisplayAnimation("intro_cutscene"));`. The client would then read this message and display whatever animation is named `"into_cutscene"`.

Comment: The format can really be anything that's convenient for your application to read and use, and compact enough for your bandwidth needs. If JSON meets those criteria for your context, then there's nothing wrong with using it. Have you encountered any problems with the formats you've tried so far that we might be able to help you overcome?

Comment: I am in the planning stage, in fact, this is my first attempt to use skeletal animation with 3D models. The animation numbers are few thousands! We are in design phase for an app that will be used for sign language for deaf people. The user will download the sentence from server via animation, ex: like chatting. That's what we are trying to do, therefore storing all animations offline on the app is inefficient.

Comment: I am in the planning stage, in fact, this is my first attempt to use skeletal animation with 3D models. The animation numbers are few thousands! . The user will download the sentence from server via animation, ex: like chatting. That's what we are trying to do, therefore storing all animations offline on the app is inefficient.